# ¿Cómo mostrar el valor de mis variables al mandar un correo desde AWS SES con python?

Tags: python, aws, lambda

tengo una duda; estoy usando AWS SES para el envío de correos en una lambda y también estoy consumiendo una API, usé la plantilla de [aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/ses/latest/dg/send-an-email-using-sdk-programmatically.html)  para python y funciona para el envío de correos, sin embargo al colocar el HTML que debo usar manda errores ya qye el HTML tiene llaves {{}} para mostrar los valores de las variables por lo que me hace pensar necesito Jinja.

Ya instalé jinja y lo importé; sólo que al usar Template para renderizar, no funciona y me dice que hay un error al consumir la API que estoy usando por lo que no manda el correo ¿Tienen idea si debo usar jinja o format() o que necesito para que pueda mostrar la información de las variables que están entre llaves {{}}? Porque todo funciona bien, excepto por ese detalle

```html
 BODY_HTML ="""<!DOCTYPE html>
            
            <body style="background-color: #FFFF;"> 
                {{NumberWeek}},   {{StartWeek}}  {{EndWeek}}  {{ActualMonth}}
            </body>
            </html>"""
```